# NodeJS MongoDB connection not functioning

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I am trying to connect my Mongodb to Nodejs but for some reason my connection is not going through I get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdZzQ.png)

and below is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:3100/myorders';

const databaseName = 'myorders';
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

let mydb;

MongoClient.connect(url,(err,client)=>{
  assert.equal(null,err);
  mydb = client.mydb.connect(databaseName);
  console.log("Connection runnning");
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3100, () =>{
   console.log('It works');
});
```

I also have my mongodb server running as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3hT5.png)

I have done this connection in the past but I have not come across this problem. What could be the issue.

Comment: Is your MongoDB server really running on port 3100? And not `const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myorders';`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change as

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myorders';
```

because your node server is on 3100 but your mongodb server is on 27017

Comment: fixed it now I get this client.mydb is not a function

Comment: checkout this link you are doing everything wrong 
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html